# How to open .ics file with Calendar

Tags: calendar

Friends and businesses send me .ics file which contain dates for appointments. How can I import these files into the Calendar app?

Comment: What happened when you choose "add" and then select the file?

Comment: I'm asking about the gnome-calendar app that came with Ubuntu Focal Fosse. I can find  no 'add' button.

Comment: top right,. calendar icon. manage -> add new -> the popup has an import where it shows an ics as an example.

Comment: The original question still stands. There is no such thing as "add". There does happen to be a "+". That takes you "unnamed event". No option anywhere to add an .ics.
I, too, am looking for that answer.
Calendar 3.36.2
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 10):

In the top right 'manage your calendar' menu (left to the 'sandwich menu'):

Manage Calendars -> Import calendar -> "file browser" icon.

[image: menu]
[image: import calendar]

Comment: I'm asking about the gnome-calendar app that came with Ubuntu Focal Fosse. I can find  no 'Manage calendars', 'sandwich menu' nor 'import'. But it _does_ automatically sync with my Google calendar through my gmail account.

Comment: Well, I'm talking about the exact same app, version 3.36.1. Is your system up to date?

Comment: Edited with an image. You may want to do the same (care not to share personal information).

Comment: right click a day and you can "add" a ics. There is also "import'  that accepts an ics @bigby can you add the image from manage calendars, add new -> it has an example with a dummy ics in it

Comment: @Rizin Sure thing!

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Comment: @ErnyCowan please accept this detailed answer that was prepared for you to show your appreciation.

Comment: This doesn't let you add an .ics file's events to an existing calendar

Comment: I'd like to import an outlook calendar ics to ubuntu 22.04. The system requires a "user" and "password" for the connection. However, I can't get through with my outlook email address and password.

Answer (score 0):

Click Addons -> Extensions -> Search Eventview -> add to extension ...

It was used to open .ics files in Thunderbird to view invites.